# Embedded SurveyMonkey survey not appearing on mobile

Tags: mobile, surveymonkey

I'm looking to embed an existing survey monkey survey into a webpage, following the instructions here:

http://help.surveymonkey.com/articles/en_US/kb/Website-Collector

which is working perfectly on desktop and tablet sizes, but for some reason not working on mobile (either on an android device or in chrome emulator)

The following steps appear to be working:

- Loading embed script into the page
- Embed script calls surveymonkey.com, and retrieves the SMCX script
- SMCX.boot() is called

But, the survey (or its markup) does not appear in the page.

Has anyone else run into this issue? What other additional information can I provide?

Comment: AFAIK the website collector doesn't work on mobile - you need to iframe a regular weblink collector.  You may want to raise this with support@surveymonkey.com

Answer (score 3):

The Website Collector used to work everywhere, but they changed their API and now document that mobile is not supported.

http://help.surveymonkey.com/articles/en_US/kb/Website-Collector

```
"Website Collectors display on desktop browsers only—not on mobile devices or tablets."
```

It's actually worse than not supporting mobile or tablets, their surveys don't even load on desktop browsers if your browser is currently 760 pixels or less wide.

The solution is to just iframe the web link in manually.

```
<iframe height="500" width="500" src="https://www.surveymonkey.com/r/XL3DDMS"></iframe>
```

Comment: Seems pretty crazy to me; if it just plain doesn't appear on small screens, I can't really think of a time you'd be able to actually use it (they should at least spin up a placeholder message, right?). But this seems to be the case.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the answer of using iframe, for iPhone, both in Safari and Chrome rendered a weird view (the spacing between each question is extremely large), and I finally tackled it by turn off the "One Question at a Time" option, hope this helps someone.

[image]